# Problema para tabular informacion de laravel a HTML

Tags: html, mysql, laravel

estoy intentando tabular una informacion de tal manera que quede asi [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el problema es que al colocar mas de un evento por persona deforma la tabla, creo que es un problema de logica ya que entra en tres foreach.

asi queda[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo aca el repositorio del projecto https://github.com/majiar15/dcc

codigo vista de la tabla de actividades.
intento mostrar los eventos a los que asistieron cada persona, las horas totales asistidas las calculo por el controlador  y la paso a la vista, el resto de la informacion viene de la base de datos

```
<table border='1' id="hours">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Asistentes</th>
            <th>Horas Asistidas totales</th>
            @foreach($eventos as $evento)
            <td>{{$evento->nom_evento}}<br>
                {{'('.$evento->fecha.')'}}
            </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    @foreach ($horas as $hora)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{$hora['name']." ".$hora['last_name'] }}
        </td>    
        <td>
            {{$hora['hours']}}
        </td>    
        @foreach($user_events as $user_event)
            @if($hora['id'] == $user_event->user_id)     

                @foreach($eventos as $evento)

                    @if (isset($advance) && $advance && $loop->index >= $index)

                        @if($evento->id == $user_event->event_id)

                            <td>{{$hora['name'].'-'.$evento->nom_evento.'-'.$user_event->user_id}}</td>

                            <!--<td>1</td>-->
                            @break

                        @else                  
                            <td>0</td>
                            <?php
                                $advance=false;
                            ?>
                        @endif                        
                    @else
                        @if($evento->id == $user_event->event_id)

                            <td>{{$hora['name'].'-'.$evento->nom_evento.'-'.$user_event->user_id}}</td>

                            <!--<td>1</td>-->
                            <?php
                                $advance=true;
                                $index = $loop->index;  

                            ?>                              
                        @else                  
                            <td>0</td>

                        @endif    
                    @endif  
                @endforeach    
            @endif  
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach   
</table>
```

diseño de base de datos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Déjanos ver la sección donde generas los `<tr>`

Comment: @Shaz ya coloque toda la seccion, desde el comienzo al final de la tabla

Comment: Efectivamente en alguna parte de tu bucle, realiza 3 iteraciones mas de las necesarios al añadir las columnas y por eso el formato de la tabla no es correcto. Si tienes xDebug en PHPStorm puede probar a depurar el bucle y ver donde realizas las iteraciones de mas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto descargare el phpStorm, normalmente uso vs code y no me brinda herramienta de depuración

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código que tienes en tu repositorio, es un poco extenso, poco diciente y además no es un código escrito correctamente dentro de los estándares de Laravel, por lo cual te sugeriría antes que nada, que aproveches la funcionalidad del Framework, y que sigas sus convenciones y buenas prácticas.

---

El error está en la sección donde iteras para generar los `<tr>`, puesto que deberías generar más de una fila cuando la persona asistió a más de un evento.

Revisa la lógica detrás de este código, para que genere más de una vez la fila, cuando la persona ha asistido a más de un evento:

Controlador:

```
                $horas_volunter[$u->id] = [
                    'id' =>$id,
                    'name' => $u->name,
                    'last_name' => $u->last_name,
                    'hours' => $hTotal,

                ];
```

Vista:

```
@foreach ($horas as $hora)
<tr>
    <td>
        {{$hora['name']." ".$hora['last_name'] }}
    </td>    
    <td>
        {{$hora['hours']}}
    </td>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en laravel todavía desconozco mucho del framework. Mejoraré el código e intentaré meter en un solo arreglo la asistencia de los usuarios